# How do people recognize the Miraculous holders?

Tags: miraculous-ladybug

Physical appearance and behavior do not reveal a Miraculous holder's identity (e.g., Marinette looks and sounds like Ladybug, but no one connects the two).

However, people seem to know basic characteristics of the Miraculous holders, such as approximate age and gender (e.g., Hawk Moth calls the heroes "young" in Season 2 Episode 25 "Mayura (Heroes' Day - Part 2)").

Also, people can recognize the Miraculous holders' voices, even when they're detransformed (e.g., Marinette still recognizes Cat Noir's voice, even when it's actually Adrien detransformed on the other side of the tunnel in Season 2 Episode 25 "Mayura (Heroes' Day - Part 2)").

In Miraculous Ladybug Season 3 Episode 16 "Reflekdoll",

> Marinette and Adrien swap Miraculouses.

However, Adrien seems to instantly recognize that Ladybug is the same person

> who is using the cat Miraculous, as Lady Noir.

Also, Hawk Moth and Mayura

> realize that the two have swapped Miraculouses.

How do people recognize that they're the same Miraculous holders, without even hearing their voices?